# Extract "emotion words" / affect words from english corpus?

Tags: nltk, wordnet

I have lots of English language text and am looking for a way to extract the words that have emotional content, such as "anger," "hate," "paranoid," "exited," and so on. Is there a way to do this with NLTK or WordNet?

Comment: Try searching for sentiwordnet of English in NLTK. This is what you should be looking for, wordnet won't be of any help in this case.

Comment: Try this http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html

Comment: That works. If you can make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SentiWordNet Interface in NLTK to check for the emotional content of an English word. Usage from [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html).

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn

>>> list(swn.senti_synsets('breakdown'))
[SentiSynset('dislocation.n.02'),
 SentiSynset('breakdown.n.02'),
 SentiSynset('breakdown.n.03'),
 SentiSynset('breakdown.n.04')]

>>> breakdown = swn.senti_synset('breakdown.n.03')
>>> print(breakdown)
<breakdown.n.03: PosScore=0.0 NegScore=0.25>
>>> breakdown.pos_score()
0.0
>>> breakdown.neg_score()
0.25
>>> breakdown.obj_score()
0.75
```