# Is there a python library similar to the R akfl package 'syuzhe'?

Tags: python, r, sentiment-analysis

I need to analyze the emotions of some reviews. I do not need the polarity (actually I did it with VADER). I need to know if reviews express joy or anger or some of the eight emotions (anger, anticipation, disgust, fear, joy, sadness, surprise, trust).

I know that in R we can work with 'syuzhe' package based on the NRC Word-Emotion Association Lexicon of Saif Mohammad and Peter Turney With the function `get_nrc_sentiment` that calls the NRC sentiment dictionary to calculate the presence of eight different emotions and their corresponding valence in a text file. But in python, I have not found any library that does something similar. I have read about its implementation in python [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775282/extract-emotion-words-affect-words-from-english-corpus), and [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Python-module-which-implements-NLP-emotion-recognition-with-the-NRC-Emotion-Lexicon)]. I have read about [SentiWordNet](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html) but I do not how to use it in python to obtain what I want. My dataset is not labelled so I would not want to use Machine Learning.

So the question is, is there any python equivalent of R's syuzhe?

Answer (score 1):

You can see [aylien](https://aylien.com/) (`pip install aylien-apiclient`), and get an eye on [Watson by IBM](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk).

Comment: you mean "no", don't you? Is this still the answer in 2021?